# Display Results By Date

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE Date = '$date'"); 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
    $d="D-";
         // output data of each row
        echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Date</th><th>Product Code</th><th>Description</th><th>Delivery Order</th><th>Cartons</th><th>Items</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Sent_To</th></tr>";


       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
       {
           echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Date"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Product_Code"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Description"]. "</td><td>".$d. $row["DEO"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Cartons"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Items"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Quantity"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Sent_To"]. "</td></tr>";
       }
       echo "</table>";
```

Hello Guys When i echo $date it prints the date correctly but when i run this query i get an error

> Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rmt\displaydate.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\rmt\displaydate.php on line 11

Please help me to fix this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using both `mysqli_query` and `$conn->query` right after each other, pick one or the other :)

Comment: data base date format and the $date format is not matching

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `mysqli_query` followed by `$conn->query` on the *result* from the first query. You only need to call one of them, for example;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stock WHERE Date = '$date'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: @UmairAyaz If the answer helped, you can use the checkmark to the left of the score to the left to mark it as answering your question.